# docker: port mapping not working on non default machine

Tags: linux, networking, docker, docker-machine

When playing with `docker` I discovered something strange (at least to me). I created a container by:

```
docker run -p 8080:80 nginx
```

And no matter what I try. I couldn't see anything from `http://localhost:8080`. Finally I figured out that I did

```
eval $(docker-machine env foo)
```

and switched to a different machine. When switching back to the default machine, the HTTP server works fine again.

Could somebody explain why this is?

I'm using Docker for Mac 1.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can guess from your info that you're using Docker toolbox (with VirtualBox probably). Docker toolbox creates a linux host (based on the boot2docker image) and runs your nginx container inside that host. the `-p 8080:80` will export port 80 in nginx to 8080 **on the host**. So to access it from your computer, you need to use http://HOST-IP-ADDRESS:8080.

You can find your host IP by using `docker-machine ls`

An alternative to Docker toolbox is to use Docker for Mac or Docker for Windows (google them). These remove the need for VirtualBox. Your computer essentially becomes the host for running docker containers. In that case, running `http://localhost:8080` would give your your nginx server.

Comment: thanks. I'm using Docker for Mac 1.12. Indeed if I use the IP of the residing machine, it works. But still, what magic is behind the default machine?

Comment: Docker 4 mac installs a very small hypervisor called [xhyve](https://github.com/mist64/xhyve). An Alpine Linux host is then created and the docker daemon runs in it. By default, the containers run in `host` mode, which means that they share the Alpine Linux host networking stack, which itself shares the OSX networking stack (localhost).

It's all transparent to the users though. When you use the docker client on your mac, it looks as if OSX is the host.

Comment: last question: about the transparent part: is it bridging?

Comment: Not, it's using `host` mode which means that it's using the same network as the host. ie: containers all have the same ip as the host. Host networking is faster than virtual networking (bridge and specially overlay) but the price to pay is loss of isolation (private network are great to hide your internals). Overlay network is also required when you start dealing with clustered environment (swarm).

Comment: Down voting because `docker for mac` still has a VM as noted by @Alkaline, but it isn't always transparent to users. For example a container cannot access the host machine without some manual workaround see https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/ and https://forums.docker.com/t/should-docker-run-net-host-work/14215/2 and https://forums.docker.com/t/access-host-not-vm-from-inside-container/11747/23

Comment: @shusson The original question was edited after I answered anyway (using Docker for Mac). The correct answer is actually much simpler now, just unsetting the DOCKER_xxx environment variables should do the trick and point the client to the Docker for Mac host (xhyve|alpine). The problem you describe is container to host communication, which is a different topic.